# Adding a dictionary to a list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I am cycling through a CSV file containing details of parents of students and loading the data into a dictionary with the student's ID as the key.

Each dictionary value will have a list of parents. Each parent is a dictionary which has their name and email address. I can add the first parent without an issue, but when I try to append the second parent to the list, I get an error. This is my code:

```
def parentsFile(location):
    with open(location) as readfile:
        doc = csv.DictReader(readfile, delimiter=",")
        data = {}
        # Read the data and add to multi-dimentional dictionary
        for row in doc:
            if row["ID"] not in data:  # No previous entry for student
                data[row["ID"]] = {}
                data[row["ID"]][0] = {}
                data[row["ID"]][0]["lastName"] = row["Last_Name"]
                data[row["ID"]][0]["firstName"] = row["First_Name"]
                data[row["ID"]][0]["email"] = row["Email_Address"]
            else:   # There is a previous entry, this is the second parent entry
                new = {}
                new["lastName"] = row["Last_Name"]
                new["firstName"] = row["First_Name"]
                new["email"] = row["Email_Address"]
                data[row["ID"]].append(new)
    return data
```

This is the error message that I am getting:

```
data[row["ID"]].append(new)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

All of my Googling tells me that I can append to a list inside of a dictionary. Is it that my issue is in adding a dictionary to a list which is inside of a dictionary?

Comment: Your trying to append to a dictionary. You define data[row[‘ID’]] = {}

Comment: Should be: `data[row["ID"]] = []`

Comment: Thank you, that was it! The error message should have given it away. I don't know why I couldn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

As Hamza and Stephen pointed out, I had declared my second level as a dictionary instead of a list. This caused my error. I have changed my code to this:

```
for row in doc:
            if row["ID"] not in data:  # No previous entry for student
                new = {}
                new["lastName"] = row["Last_Name"]
                new["firstName"] = row["First_Name"]
                new["email"] = row["Email_Address"]
                data[row["ID"]] = []
                data[row["ID"]].append(new)
            else:   # There is a previous entry, this is the second parent entry
                num = len(data[row["ID"]])
                new = {}
                new["lastName"] = row["Last_Name"]
                new["firstName"] = row["First_Name"]
                new["email"] = row["Email_Address"]
                data[row["ID"]].append(new)
```